# What is the historical composition by party of Australian parliament (HOR & Senate)?

Tags: parties, australia, senate, parliament

I know from http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Australian_Senate#Historical what the composition the senate has been, but I would also like to know how many seats were for each member of the Coalition, and the historical composition of the House of Representatives. If you happen to know where to find similar for Australian states I would also be interested.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found it here: http://www.aph.gov.au/About_Parliament/Parliamentary_Departments/Parliamentary_Library/pubs/rp/rp1415/FedElect/FedElectj, http://www.aph.gov.au/About_Parliament/Parliamentary_Departments/Parliamentary_Library/pubs/rp/rp1415/FedElect/FedElectk, http://www.aph.gov.au/About_Parliament/Parliamentary_Departments/Parliamentary_Library/pubs/rp/rp1415/FedElect/FedElectl.

I Googled "history of seat results australia house of representatives" instead of using "historical composition".